# How to predict strategy based on given data using Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, exploratory-factor-analysis

My basic goal is to predict strategy based on given data for instance

a) Predict what formation In a football match will maximize my winning rate

b) Predict what product combination will maximize my sales rate in the Grocery store

How to deal with such problems in machine learning? What approach is used in such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are optimization problems. Typically it requires two parts:

- One needs a function $y=f(x)$ which returns the expected outcome $y$ for a particular "strategy" $x$. The way to do it depends on the actual problem, for example sometimes it can be a custom deterministic function. Otherwise it can be a supervised regression model, but then one needs a training set.
- The second part is the optimization per se: exploring the set of possible "strategies" $X$, applying the function $f$ to every candidate $x\in X$ to obtain the corresponding outcome, then pick the maximum. Genetic learning is a common approach for exploring the search space, but it depends on the problem.

Comment: Might sound silly!  If I am not wrong just like what  Deep mind Alpha fold is doing? or for instance Discovering a drug for a disease Like Remdisiver was predicted that it will be effective on Covid-19

Comment: @ShaelanderChauhan I don't know the details about these systems, but they must have something similar to the two steps above. Without the first part it's impossible to evaluate one of the "strategies", so it's impossible to find the best one. Of course this is just the big picture, the details are specific to the target problem.

Comment: Thankyou for the great insights.